# регулярное выражение для фильтрации input под число либо число с дробной частью

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, регулярные-выражения

хочу разрешить пользователям вводить в поле ввода только числа либо дробные числа, для этого использую регулярку

```
$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^\d.,]/g, ""));
```

Но возникает проблема - можно вводить несколько точек/запятых, как регулярной фильтровать ввод более одной точки либо запятой?

Answer (score 1):

Вот нужная вам регулярка:

```
[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+
```

`[-+]?` - Знак

`[0-9]*\.?` - Целая часть числа с точкой, если число - дробь.

`[0-9]+` - Либо дробная часть, либо целое число.

Comment: не соображу как вашу регулярку заточить под мои нужды, нужно что бы введеная вторая и последующие точки/запятые заменялись на пустоту как в моем примере